# I have no idea how to make request-form

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

I want to add request-form on my application to invite friends.

I checked http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/
and I used Example PHP Invite Page code on server side as invited.php, but it just show blank page.I guess this code is old. facebook.php doesn't have the method require_frame and require_login.

Please let me know how can I make request form.

Comment: You are probably best off debugging what you have. Turn on PHP's error reporting to see the problems instead of the blank page

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Pekka. I could solve this issue. Appreciate for your kindness!

Answer (score 1):

Which method you are following???Iframe or FBML??

If Iframe then

```
<fb:serverfbml width="615">
<script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:request-form action="http://example.com/"
        method="POST"
        invite="true"
        type="Example"
        content="Blah Blah Blah <fb:req-choice url='http://example.com/' label='Join' />">
        <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false"
            bypass="cancel"
            cols=4
            rows=4
            actiontext="Select Facebook Friends"/>
    </fb:request-form>
</script>
```

If you are following FBML then

```
invite="true"
    type="Example"
    content="Blah Blah Blah <fb:req-choice url='http://example.com/' label='Join' />">
    <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false"
        bypass="cancel"
        cols=4
        rows=4
        actiontext="Select Facebook Friends"/>
</fb:request-form>
```

I am able to get the result in both cases..

Comment: Dear Mr Damodaran. I could make it on my application!! Thank you so much for your great help...

Comment: Actually it doesn't work on IE. Could somebody let me know how can I make it, please?